# Working with HResult, interop and related things in C#

Tags: c#, interop, hresult

I am working on a project in C# to create a forms application. I would like to use IFileDialog and other functionality that is part of the native Windows API (or however ti should be called).

Starting out I knew absolutely nothing about interop or the Windows API. I am starting to learn but at times it can be hard to find very basic info on certain aspects. Therefore I have a (probably trivial/stupid) questions:

HResults are used often. As I understand, HResults are nothing more than a 32 bit entity where the different bits supply info on the result of certain operations. In some code I found online I often see things like `int hres = -2147467259;`. Being a total noob I went to check what this means. `-2147467259` is `0xFFFFFFFF80004005` and in the online documentation at MSDN I can see that `0x80004005` signifies `E_FAIL` aka unspecified error. My question is, what is up with the `FFFFFFFF` part? Couldn't they just have used `int hres = 0x80004005`? Maybe this is very obvious and I'm a total noob, but still :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFFFFFFF part is because your HResult is negative.

That's how computers store negative numbers using [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Check out this calculation (my emphasis):
-2147467259 = 0xFFFFFFFF**80004005**
-2147467259 + 2^32 (rollover) = 2147500037 = 0x**80004005**

Answer (score 0):

On 32 bit platforms an `int` is 32 bits long which is 4 bytes of 8 hexadecimal digits. So `E_FAIL` would be  `0x80004005`, (which is what the code you pasted shows. If you dump this value on a 64 bit machine then it'll take up twice as much storage and since numbers are sign extended and the leading 8 (binary `100`) means the sign bit is `1` then it's ones all the way. `1111` in binary is `F` in hex which brings all the `F`s you see.

Comment: I pretty much expected this to be the case (the leading F's). I can see that there might be a difference between 32 abd 54 bit representations of a number but I am still wondering why E_FAIL would not be represented by 1000000000000000 0100000000000101 and why it specifically is chosen to be 1111111111111111 0100000000000101. If I myself want to write code that passes back an E_FAIL could I do something like return 2147500037 instead of -2147467259? I don't get this :)